# PostgreSQL data not showing up in WFS connection in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geoserver, postgresql

QGIS<------>GeoServer<------>PostgreSQL DB (with geometry column)

My connections are as shown above.

Task: connect QGIS to PostgreSQL db via GeoServer such that polygon can be edited in QGIS and should also reflect in DB.

Versions:
geoserver 2.23.2,
QGIS Windows 3.34.0,
GeoServer hosted on OS Linux 20.04,
PostgreSQL version 14.8.

The polygon geometry is stored in a geometry column in DB.

Problem: The data in the DB is properly showing up in GeoServer (verified from layer preview) and can be viewed in QGIS when using WMS connection (polygons are displayed). When using a WFS connection the connection is established but data is not showing up. The feature count is zero and attribute in layer properties is empty.

Note: the whole table in db is pusblished as a layer and the db user used to connect to geoserver only has read access. (I know it requires write access also but it will be implemented if the data can at least show up). GeoServer (Tomcat) is hosted on a Linux system, PostgreSQL is a service from azure, QGIS is on Windows (mostly Windows 11).

I am new to this field.

Comment: Does a command line WFS request produce the expected output? What is the request being sent to the GeoServer by QGIS (use network logging to see)? what does the GeoServer log file say? what does the QGIS log file say?

Comment: changes: 'user' has read and write access, now attribute and feature count is showing up. new error in qgis log: WFS exception report (code=NoApplicableCode text=org.opengis.referencing.NoSuchAuthorityCodeException: No authority was defined for code "". Did you forget "AUTHORITY:NUMBER"?

Comment: any suggestion on how to complete this task:-
if a table has 100 records and there are 10 people, these 10 people will be working in qgis and each person is allocated 5 individual records from the table and should only be able to access these 5 records assigned to them.
how to achieve this level of control??

Comment: looks like your coordinate reference system is missing from the request, but we need to see the actual request and the log files to be sure

Comment: I have looked into verbose logs and was able solve the problem.
Thank you for the guidance.

Comment: then please add an answer to your question to help out future users